# How to save a group of selected Models from a CollectionView in Backbone Marionette?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js, marionette, backbone.js-collections

I am using Backbone Marionette framework and I have situation like this

[image]

Here every row is a model and this is a Marionette CollectionView holding the collection of contacts. Now on click on submit button user can select as many contacts as he wants and when he click on submit I have to call on each model. So what is the best way to do it.

First of all I am not getting how to do it. I know how to call save on single model. I have searched a couple of posts but they are not providing the solution.

Comment: maintain a flag in model. when you send this collection for save filter by that flag.

Answer (score 2):

What you want, is an array of all the models that were selected by the user, so you can access those models one by one.

There are two solutions to your problem. When an onSelect event is triggered by the user, you can either

1) do nothing

2) save a reference to the selected model

Then, when the onSubmit event happens, depending on what you chose above, you have to

(1) parse the HTML of each view in the table, checking if the 'checkbox' is checked, and if so, access the model via the view's `model` property

(2) or, since you already saved an array with references to the selected models, you can just iterate over said array

**Where does the code have to reside?**

Since you want to access all models that were rendered within a Marionette.CollectionView, the code that does that needs to reside in said Marionette.CollectionView, because only there do you have access to all those models.

If you follow method (2), i.e. save a reference to the selected model at the time of the select event, that code needs to reside in the Marionette.ItemView of the respective model.

**Example for solution (2)**

```
var selectedModels = [];

var ItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    events: {
        'click checkbox': function () {
            selectedModels.push(this.model);
        } 
    }
});

var CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: ItemView,
    events: {
        'click .submit': function () {
            _( selectedModels ).invoke(someFunction);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to keep in mind when you are iterating through the array of selected models, that it will be a good idea to pass the whole array to the backend and sort it out there (save each model). This will help you reduce the amounts of calls you make to your backend, making the user experience more friendly.